# Unable to use SET key word in Spring JDBC and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, spring-jdbc

I am trying to use below mentioned query in my `spring jdbc template`, but getting bad `sql` grammar exception. Is there any other way to fix this problem except stored procedure.

```
SET @row_number:=0; 
SELECT * FROM(SELECT *,@row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number FROM COURSE 
ORDER BY C_ID) As a where a.row_number BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 limit 15;
```

Comment: show us the *Exception*

Answer (score 1):

why you need `@row_number` in select query of `COURSE`? If pagination is your concern then use default mysql limit query.

```
SELECT * FROM COURSE limit ?,15;
```

pass the parameter from where user need to view 15 result set, please note it will start from 0.